# Performance Reduction While Using SQLite3 Interface In Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am learning SQLite3 and using it through Python interface.

My SQLite3 script includes several view creation and a `SELECT * FROM ViewX LIMIT N;` statement at the end.

When I run it in SQLite3 on shell, it is instantaneous (The version of SQLite3 is 3.7.7.1) 
On the other hand, when I run it in Python using executescript, it takes much more time (The version of SQLite3 in Python is 3.8.8.1)

I was curious why this is happening.

The output of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` is: 
In Shell:

```
0|0|1|SCAN TABLE Table1 AS T1 (~1000000 rows)
0|1|2|SEARCH TABLE Table2 AS T2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|2|0|SEARCH TABLE Table3 AS T3 USING INDEX index_3 (x_id=?) (~10 rows)
```

In Python:

```
(0, 0, 1, 'SCAN TABLE Table1 AS T1')
(0, 1, 2, 'SEARCH TABLE Table2 AS T2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)')
(0, 2, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE Table3 AS T3 USING INDEX index_3 (x_id=?)')
```

Comment: How much longer? You have to account for some time to open the file and read the content

Comment: @cricket_007
Thank you for your response.
It depends. Some of my databases are big. In this case, it may take minutes.
That was what I was guessing too, but I did not expect this much difference.
I want to improve it, but could not come up with any solution so far.

I need to use create_function on some of the views. Otherwise, I could probably be able to use os.system command as a workaround.

Comment: If you run the raw query string in python rather than execute the script, what happens?

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you mean my last SELECT statement? It is already separated.

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) in both environments.

Comment: @CL. I have added it to the explanation of question.

Comment: FYI -- backticks for code formatting are appropriate for segments of less than a single line; four-space indents (as created by the `{}` button in the [edit] interface when a multi-line block is selected) are appropriate for longer sections.

Comment: Show the Python code that executes the query and reads the results.

Comment: @CL. I am using cur.execute("SELECT * FROM  View2 LIMIT 10;". Then I have a for loop to print the result.

Comment: Any change with the [latest version](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) of the shell? Or when you do just `fetchall()` without printing?

Comment: @CL. Probably, the version will be updated in a near future. Then, I can try again.
fetchall() makes it worse since the database is huge.